# TbButton Reset does not work with redactorRow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reset, redactor

Please see the below code:

```
<?php
$label = $model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update';
$form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'article-form',
    'type' => 'horizontal',
));
?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo $label ?> Article</legend>
    <?php
    echo $form->textFieldRow($model, 'title', array('class' => 'span5', 'maxlength' => 200));
echo $form->redactorRow($model, 'content');
?>
</fieldset>
<div class="form-actions">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType' => 'submit', 'type' => 'primary', 'label' => $label)); ?>
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType' => 'reset', 'label' => 'Reset')); ?>
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array('buttonType' => 'link', 'url' => url('article/index'), 'label' => 'Cancel')); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

First I type for field: title(text field) and content(redactor)
Second I click Reset Button
=> Result: just Title field is empty text, not work for Content.

Please help me to do this!

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I don't still find the problem.
But I have solution with jquery.

```
<?php
cs()->registerScript('reset', "
    var firstContent = [];

    $('.redactor_editor').each(function(index, value) {
        firstContent.push($(this).html());
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button[type=\'reset\']').click(function() {
            $('.redactor_editor').each(function(index, value) {
                $(this).html(firstContent[index]);
            });
        }); 
    });
", CClientScript::POS_LOAD);
?>
```

It works fine!

Anybody has other solution?
Please share here!

Thank very much!